# KeyRelease Event not fired in fullscreen mode

Tags: c++, macos, sfml

Just like the title says, `KeyRelease` events aren't fired at all in fullscreen mode on Mac OS X (haven't tested Linux/Windows, may be broken as well).

Here's the code:

```
sf::ContextSettings settings;
settings.antialiasingLevel = 8;

sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode::getDesktopMode(), "My Game", sf::Style::Fullscreen, settings);
window.setFramerateLimit(60);
window.setVerticalSyncEnabled(true);
window.setMouseCursorVisible(false);

while (window.isOpen())
{

    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        // Close window : exit
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed) {
            window.close();
        }

        if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed) {
                switch (event.key.code) {
                    case sf::Keyboard::Escape: // Escape pressed : exit
                        window.close();
                        break;
                    default:
                        game->handleKeyCode(event.key.code);
                        break;
                }

        } else if(event.type == sf::Event::KeyReleased) {
                printf("KeyRelease Fired!\n");
        }
    }
}
```

If I don't use fullscreen mode, and instead initialize the `window` like so, the `KeyRelease` event works just fine:

```
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(1400, 950), "My Game", sf::Style::Default, settings);
```

Comment: It seems it's a regression from SFML 2.0... You can open an issue on https://github.com/LaurentGomila/SFML/issues

Comment: Thanks @Hiura, I added the issue. https://github.com/LaurentGomila/SFML/issues/465

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [recent commit](https://github.com/LaurentGomila/SFML/commit/e5c6f6cd7a66f2ca7a53da0813b870f69caa37e1) fix this. Compiling SFML from its git should solve this issue. See [the official tutorial](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.1/compile-with-cmake.php) for more details about the compilation.